# Adding 2 to only certain ascii values

Tags: java

I'm trying to have the user input a string and for the code to take the input and add 2 to the value. So 'a' would return 'c'. The only issue is I don't want it to happen for special characters "!", space, ', .etc. I tried If else and I got and error. Any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String inputString;
    System.out.println("Input: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    inputString = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();
    int len=inputString.length();
    char[] c = inputString.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if()
        System.out.println(c);
        else( =)    
        c[i] +=2;
        System.out.println(c);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
            String inputString;
            System.out.println("Input: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputString = sc.nextLine();
            sc.close();
            char[] c = inputString.toCharArray();
            for(char ch : c) // This iterate through the input char array.
            {
                if(ch <=91 && ch>=65 || ch<=123 && ch>=97) // ascii value of a to z and A to Z.
                System.out.println(Character.valueOf((char) (ch+2)));
                else    
                System.out.println(ch);


            }
```

Comment: Awesome, if I wanted 'y' to loop back to 'a' and 'z' to 'b'. could i just add another else statement?

Comment: use %26 + 65 or %26 + 97 to go back to 'a' or 'A'.
// % = mod 
which means 27%26 =1 //

Answer (score 0):

```
if((c[i] >= 65 && c[i] <= 90) || (c[i] >= 97 && c[i] <= 122))
{
    c[i] += 2;
    System.out.println(c);
} 
else
{
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

This will check if the character is A-Z or a-z. Alternatively you could use toUpper() or toLower() and only use one half of the if

```
if(Character.toUpperCase(c[i]) >= 65 && Character.toUpperCase(c[i]) <= 90)
{
    c[i] += 2;
    System.out.println(c);
} 
else
{
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: This code would be much clearer if you use 'A' instead of 65, etc.